# Why is this regex matching on decimals?

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a large number of text fields that need to be evaluated onkeyup to be sure nothing is entered but numbers.  Decimals are ok. So is the absence of a value.

For some reason this is matching on decimals.  Eg I type 4 and then . and it flags on .

How do I correct this?

```
var s_in = 0;
for (var i = 10; i < 19; i++) {
    var fObj = document.getElementById(field+'_'+i);
    var text = fObj.value;
    if (text) {
        var s = parseInt(text);
        var pattern = /^[+-]?(\d*\.)?\d+$/;
        var result;
        if ((result = pattern.exec(text)) != null) {
            if (s > -1) {
                s_in += s;
            }
        } else {  // not empty and not a number
            alert('The entry for Hole ' + i + ' ' + ucfirst(field) + ' is "' + text + '" This is not a number. It will be erased now.');
            fObj.value = '';
            fObj.focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex requires one or more digits after the decimal point and you have to escape the `-` in the first group).  If you don't want to require a digit after the decimal, then you can use this (changes a `+` to a `*` and puts `\` in front of the `-`):

```
/^[+\-]?(\d*\.)?\d*$/
```

Comment: Tried it but am still getting rejected on decimals.  Tried typing in 1.1 and pasting in 1.1 (in case it was weirdness with onkeyup) but both were flagged as non-numbers?  Thank you for responding!

Comment: @jerrygarciuh - you have to escape the `-` that's in the first group.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Updated it but still flagging decimals?

Comment: Sorry - my bad.  Error in my testing.  Working now.  Thankss!

Comment: @jerrygarciuh - I guess you got it sorted now, but here's an interactive tester: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/CuFbK/